# how to write the output to a file python

Tags: python, file, input, output

so I have the file: data2.txt

```
Lollypop,
Lolly pop,
ooh 
lolly,
lolly, lolly;
lollypop, lollypop,
ooh lolly, lolly, lolly,
lollypop!
ba dum dum dum ...

LOL :-)
```

i need to loop through each line of data2.txt printing only lines that contain the string 'lol' and print the output to a newfile

```
with open("data3.txt") as g:
    with open("data2.txt") as lfp:
        for lin in lfp:
            if 'lol' in lin:
                g.write(str(lin))
            elif 'LOL' in lin:
                g.write(str(lin))
            elif 'Lol' in lin:
                g.write(str(lin))
```

But I keep getting error:

```
    g.write(str(lin))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to open with `w` for writing:

```
with open("data3.txt","w") as g:
    with open("data2.txt") as lfp:
```

You can also simplify to:

```
with open("data3.txt", "w") as g, open("data2.txt") as lfp:
        for lin in lfp:
            if 'lol' in lin.lower():
                g.write(lin)
```

Or use writelines:

```
with open("data3.txt", "w") as g, open("data2.txt") as lfp:
        g.writelines(line for line in lfp if "lol" in line.lower())
```

`line` is already a string so you don't need to call `str` on it, using `"lol" in line.lower()` will match all you cases.

If you were explicitly looking for `"lol", "Lol", "LOL"`, `any` would be a nicer approach.

```
with open("data3.txt", "w") as g, open("data2.txt") as lfp:
    poss = ("lol", "Lol", "LOL")
    g.writelines(line for line in lfp 
                    if any(s in line for s in poss))
```

All the modes are explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: didn't know you can open two files on one line, nice answer!

Comment: @martijnn2008, yep, you can open as many as you want,  you can so it with any objects the support the use of a context manager

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line `with open("data3.txt") as g:`

You didn't provide `open` with a mode, and the default is `r` which is only for reading. Use `with open("data3.txt", 'w') as g:` if you want to replace the file if it is already exists or `with open("data3.txt", 'a') as g:` if you want to append to the file if it is already exists.